# Angularjs material preloading models

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angularjs-material

I am working on an application that is supposed to edit user information... I want the form to be preloaded with any information that's already in the resource... So there's a list of users and when I click on edit, the edit dialog shows up, and the information pre-fetched from that particular user should be populated in the form fields..

I have my code in this fashion:

```
<md-input-container>
     <label>Designation</label>
     <md-select
            ng-model="_dt.gradeID"
            md-selected-text="_dt.getSelectedText(_dt.grade, 'destination')"
      name="designation"
      required
      ng-change="_dt.onDesignate(_dt.gradeID)">
      <md-optgroup label="Designation" >
             <md-option
                    ng-value="pos"
                    ng-repeat="pos in _dt.designations">
                    {{pos.gradename}}
             </md-option>
         </md-optgroup>
     </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

In the controller I have the following:

```
this.$onInit = function () {
      this.user = angular.copy(item)
      // where item is any user that I'm currently editing

      // then I fetch the designation 
      // data from the server
      $category.query({table: 'grades'}, function (res) {
            this.designations = res;
      });

      // then I am trying to pre-populate the grade model, but it doesn't seem to work
      this.gradeID = this.user.gradename;
 } // on init ends
```

This is the function I call when changing between values

```
this.onDesignate = function (d) {
      this.user.gradeID = d.gradeID;
      this.grade = d.gradename;
}
```

Here is the get selected text function:

```
this.getSelectedText = function (x, y) {
      if (x !== undefined) {
          return x;
      } else {
          return "Select " + y;
      }
}
```

How can I pre-populate this md-select? Now it shows no value when I click on edit. It works very well though if I change the value (after it has already loaded - but then a user wouldn't know what value was there before) to something in the list.

Comment: id recommend starting a pen/fiddle/plunker. See if you can reproduce the same outside of your app, and also more peeps be more inclined/able to help.